# Obtener en java datos asociados a su alias desde una select

Tags: java, hibernate

tengo una funcion tal que así:

```
public List<Object[]> lanzarConsultas(String consulta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<Object[]> consultas = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    try {
        consultas = em.createNativeQuery(consulta).getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return consultas;
}
```

Y una consulta por ejemplo del tipo:

SELECT campo_id as "identificador", campo2 as "direccion" FROM ejemplo

Hay alguna manera de traer los campos asociados a su "alias", y no solo los datos como me esta trayendo ahora?

La sql la introduce el usuario, por lo que no es siempre la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Si realizas esta consulta por ejemplo:

```
consultas = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT campo_id as "identificador", campo2 as "direccion" FROM ejemplo").getResultList()
```

vas a obtener datos de dos campos que son "identificador" y "direccion", Si deseas obtener estos valores lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
for (Object[] consulta : consultas) {
    System.out.println("Identificador: " + consulta[0]
            + " Dirección: " + consulta[1]);
}
```

Comment: El problema es que yo me quiero traer una lista mapeada de "campo"-> valor.

Comment: Esta lista se tiene que generar a partir de los parametros de la consultas, no  a "piñon" a código. Ya que la select la introduce el usuario.